# pass the state of pressed buttons of different types and pass already pressed buttons to another component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component with buttons that looks like this:

```
export function Buttons({id}) {
    return (
        <>
           /* Type 1 --- SubType 1.1 */
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-11-left">left</button>
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-11-center">center</button>
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-11-right">right</button>
           /* Type 1 --- SubType 1.2 */ 
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-12-top">top</button>
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-12-middle">middle</button>
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-12-bottom">bottom</button>
         
           /* Type 2 --- SubType 2.1 */
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-21-left">left</button>
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-21-center">center</button>
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-21-right">right</button>
           /* Type 2 --- SubType 2.2 */
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-22-top">top</button>
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-22-middle">middle</button>
           <button onClick={() => {setClButtons(???)}} data-label="subtype-22-bottom">bottom</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

And these buttons have 2 types, and each type has 2 subtypes. And I want to save the state of each clicked button to a hook with an array of objects, which will be passed the click state of each button subtype.

Also, I have a `<ClickedButtons />` component that I just want to pass the clicked buttons to. For example, pass the clicked buttons via any custom attribute, like this:

```
<ClickedButtons buttons={ClButtons} />
```

Here's what the  and `<ClickedButtons />` components will look like:

```
<ClickedButtons id={1} />
<ClickedButtons id={2} />
<ClickedButtons id={3} />

<Buttons id={1} />
<Buttons id={2} />
<Buttons id={3} />
```

How it's supposed to work. For example, if you click on the button `<button onClick={() => {}} data-label="subtype-22-middle">middle</button>` from `<Buttons />` with **ID 3**, this button should be displayed in the component `<ClickedButtons />` with **ID 3**.

This is a simple example of a hook that could be in my opinion:

```
const [ClButtons, setClButtons] = useState([
  { Type1: [SubType11: { ... }, SubType12: { ... }] }, 
  { Type2: [SubType21: { ... }, SubType22: { ... }] }
]);
```

But you can ignore this hook structure, as the structure can be at your discretion!

Please help!

**EDIT**

```
<h2>ClickedButtons ID 1:</h2>

<button data-label="subtype-11-center">center</button>
<button data-label="subtype-21-right">right</button>
```

We clicked these buttons in `<Buttons id={1} />` with **ID 1**, so, it showed up in `<ClickedButtons id={1} />` with **ID 1**

```
<h2>ClickedButtons ID 2:</h2>

<button data-label="subtype-12-middle">middle</button>
<button data-label="subtype-22-middle">middle</button>
```

We clicked these buttons in `<Buttons id={2} />` with **ID 2**, so, it showed up in `<ClickedButtons id={2} />` with **ID 2**

```
<h2>ClickedButtons ID 3:</h2>

<button data-label="subtype-11-left">left</button>
<button data-label="subtype-11-right">right</button>
<button data-label="subtype-21-left">left</button>
<button data-label="subtype-22-bottom">bottom</button>
```

We clicked these buttons in `<Buttons id={3} />` with **ID 3**, so, it showed up in `<ClickedButtons id={3} />` with **ID 3**

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to save the state of each clicked button to a hook with an array of objects, which will be passed the click state of each button subtype.

Keeping track of an array of objects seems kinda overkill

---

Seems like an array with unique id (eg 2.1) should be enough.

Then `ClickedButtons` can check if some button is included in the array to alter the UI.

Small demo were we keep track of the clicked buttons in `value` state and pass that to `ClickedBUttons` component

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
    
    const onButtonClick = (e) => {
        const who = e.target.dataset.who;
        
        const ii = value.indexOf(who);
        if (ii >= 0) {
            setValue(p => {
                let n = [ ...p ];
                n.splice(ii, 1);
                return n;
            });
        } else {
            setValue(p => [ ...p, who ]);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            
            <button onClick={onButtonClick} data-who={"1.1"}>1.1</button>
            <button onClick={onButtonClick} data-who={"1.2"}>1.2</button>
            
            <button onClick={onButtonClick} data-who={"2.1"}>2.1</button>
            <button onClick={onButtonClick} data-who={"2.2"}>2.2</button>
            
            <hr />
            
            <ClickedButtons clicked={value} />
        </div>
    )
}

const ClickedButtons = ({ clicked }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <code>&lt;ClickedButtons/&gt;</code> <br />
            <ul>
                {clicked.map(c => <li><kbd>{c}</kbd></li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the main question is to have multiple `<ClickedButtons />` and multiple <Buttons />, and put the buttons based on the **id** components

Comment: `id` or `data-who` makes no difference, not sure what you're trying to say with mulitple ClickButtons components, the ClickedBUttons can map over the array and render thing needed?

Comment: it matters. because i was talking about component ID, but not button id. In your case, `who` is the button like id

Comment: So you need a `ClickedButtons` component for each type? And then the ClickedButtons component will render something with those types? Could you otherwise give a (small) example of the final DOM you're looking for?

Comment: I added an example of how I want to get. at the very bottom of my question. Thanks!

Comment: does my example make sense to you?